# Find function in Julia 1.0.2

Tags: julia

I am transitioning to Julia 1.0.2 and I realized that the find function is not defined. In a previous version (Julia 0.6) I could write

```
find(x -> x<0, my_var)
```

In order to get the negative elements of the array called my_var. When I run the same code in Julia 1.0.2 I get the following error:

```
UndefVarError: find not defined
```

I couldn't find whether the find function is implemented under a different name or if it has been dropped. Is there any Julia 1.0.2 function that would be equivalent to the find function in previous Julia versions?

Comment: Very strong recommendation: transition via v0.7. In this case, v0.7 would have given you a deprecation warning telling you to use `findall` instead of `find`. Note, v0.7 is exactly the same as v1.0, but with deprecation warnings for thousands of little gotchas like this one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `filter()`:

```
julia> filter(x -> x<0, -5:5)
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
 -5
 -4
 -3
 -2
 -1
```

Another option is to use `findall()` to get the indices of elements:

```
julia> indices = findall(x -> x<0, -5:5)
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
```

You can use `getindex()` to get the actual values, e.g.:

```
julia> getindex(-5:5,indices)
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
 -5
 -4
 -3
 -2
 -1
```

Comment: The last example can be also simply written as `(-5:5)[indices]` or `getindex(-5:5, indices)` as broadcasting here is not needed.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for